# Continuous complex functions

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-analysis

1. We are given with a map $g:\bar D\to \Bbb C $, which is continuous on $\bar D$ and analytic on $D$. Where $D$ is a ***bounded domain*** and $\bar D=D\cup\partial D$. Then $\partial(g(D))\subseteq g(\partial D).$(I already know, how to prove it).

I need two examples:

a) First, to show that the above inclusion can be strict, that is: $\partial(g(D))\not= g(\partial D).$

b) Second example, I need to show that conclusion in (1) is not true if $D$ is  not bounded.

---

There is an example, I was working on yesterday. But I couldn't understand it completely.

a) If we take $g(z)= z^2$ and $D$ =\begin{cases}z, & \text{where 1<|z|<2} \\\end{cases}
This $g$ is not 1-1.

Now, *we want to prove that $g(\partial D)\not\subset \partial(g(D)) $.* Therefore, we need to show that $\exists $ some $z\in g(\partial D)$ but $z \not\in \partial(g(D))$. 
How will we show that ???

I want to talk about domain $D$ and its image by map $g$. Please check it:[image]

I am not sure that I am taking right domain.
??

Comment: What is "(1)" ?

Comment: @Emil Which (1) are you talking about?

Comment: The one in “Second example, I need to show that conclusion in (1) is not true if $D$ is not bounded”.

Comment: I see, I forgot to mention it. I was talking about the statement. i.e. inclusion $\partial(g(D))\subseteq g(\partial D).$ is not possible.

Answer (score 5):

1. Take $f(z)=z^2$, and $D$ some excentric disc, for example $|z-1|<2$.
2. Take $D=C$, $f(z)=e^z$. $\partial D=\emptyset$, $f(\partial D)=\emptyset$, but
   $\partial f(C)=\{0\}$, one point.

Comment: What is the difference in between excentric and usual open disc?

Comment: Excentric just means that the center is not at the origin.

Comment: I see. Alexandre can you please elaborate these examples bit further. I couldn't see that how do these examples work. 
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what to elaborate. For example 1, just sketch the picture.

Comment: I want to see that with your function $z^2$ and Domain(excentric circle); $g(\partial D)\not\subset \partial(g(D)).$

Comment: Make a picture and you will see.

Comment: Alright, Let me draw it. Thanks

Comment: What are our $g(\partial D)$ and $\partial(g(D))$. I couldn't visualize them.

Answer (score 2):

if we take domain, $D'=D(1,2) $ \ $(-1,0)$ (We are eliminating the interval $(-1,0)$). We get $g(D')= D$ and $\partial D'=\partial D\cup (-1,0)$. Now we are done.